# FTPLIB error socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftplib

I'm trying to download a file from an FTP server using FTPlib but i keep getting the error below. I tried several methods found on SO namely editing the etc/host file and adding the computer name after the local host IP but that doesnt work either.

Any help is much appreciated. (running a mac, python 3.7, macOS Mojave 10.14.2)

**Code im trying to run:**

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP('myftpurl')
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ftplib.py", line 117, in **init**
    self.connect(host)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ftplib.py", line 152, in connect
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
**socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ftp = FTP('myftpurl')
```

It is not clear what `myftpurl` actually contains in your specific code.
But given its name I assume that you've tried something like `ftp://example.com`. Only, as [clearly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP) `FTP(...)` does not expect a URL but instead a hostname or IP, i.e. `FTP('example.com')` and not `FTP('ftp://example.com')`.

Given a URL like you probably do will result in treating that URL as hostname, i.e. doing a lookup for the hostname `ftp://example.com`. Since such a host does not exist you get an error.